# Prevent further execution of calling function in C#

Tags: c#, function, methods

I have a function, which executes on button click and it looks like this

```
private void Login_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CheckFields())
            return;

        if (!WritePerforceSettingsXml(rewriteSettingsCheckbox.IsChecked.Value))
            return;

        Dictionary<string, string> installerToUpdateList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (!GetUpdateListFilesFromXml(ref installerToUpdateList))
            return;            

       //some code
    }
```

As you can see, i have some functions which check correctness of input values or just have "try-catch" operators inside, and if "catch" case happens or input is not valid further execution of caller (Login_Button_Click function) should be prevented. 
But all functions returning "bool" aren't look right as i think.

Is there any other ways to prevent calling function from further execution?

Comment: what is your specific issue with the functions returning a bool? You just think it looks ugly?

Comment: The only alternative is to throw exceptions inside the methods being called - but that doesn't look like the correct approach for this particular code. So I think it's fine to use bools like you are doing.

Comment: You could "OR" the function returns together with `||` in one if statement.  That will short circuit with the first one that returns true, but I don't think that would look or be much better.

Comment: @KateGregory Not ugly but i'm not sure if my code is right. I'm doing refactoring of my code at the moment, and if i refactor bad code to another bad code it would be worthless XD

Comment: @juharr I had same thoughts and thats why i'm here asking this question=)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you for your answer, seems it is the only ways to do this.

Comment: To me your approach looks right. You're making it clear the reasons you might leave this function early. Exceptions wouldn't be good choices for things that aren't exceptional.

Comment: I agree with @KateGregory. I'm a big fan of early returning and de-nesting code, which is why I wouldn't do something like the answer that @sydan provided. The only thing I disagree with is the use of `ref` in a method, because I consider it a code smell.

Comment: @Cameron Thank you for answer! And what you can recommend to do with `ref`? My func fills the `Dictionary<>` with values and I cannot create and return `Dictionary<>`, because `bool` is already returning. Should i use `out` or what?

Comment: @AlexeevMikhail That's hard to say. I would probably use `out`. It guarantees that the value is the result of that method. Another would be returning `null` rather than `false` and then null checking the value, but I think using `out` is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I would invert the Boolean conditions:

```
private void Login_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckFields() && WritePerforceSettingsXml(rewriteSettingsCheckbox.IsChecked.Value))
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> installerToUpdateList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (GetUpdateListFilesFromXml(ref installerToUpdateList))
        {         
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

This way you're checking positively which is clearer and easier to follow, you also reduce the number or returns in a function which increases readability. The code also has less lines.